# Got syntax error in an Apex class but compiled successfully. Any thoughts please?

Tags: eclipse, compile-error

In eclipse one of my Apex class showing syntax error on a particular line of code. But it compiled successfully without any issues. Any thoughts on why i am getting this error? Please see the error description and screen shot.

> Syntax(error = UnexpectedSyntaxError(loc = RealLoc(startIndex = 5944,
>   endIndex = 5948, line = 893, column = 9), message = mismatched input
>   'Case' expecting RCURLY))

[image]

Comment: the way to diagnose this is to selectively remove bits from the offending statement (by commenting out) until the error goes away - then you may have something that can be reported to SFDC Support if it is a compiler bug

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me as though the editor thinks that should be a subquery starting on that line beginning with `c.asset.description`, but apparently it doesn't need to be, so the compiler allowed it to compile anyway. Either that or it's unhappy that you used a hard return on the first line of the query rather than letting the word wrap do it's thing.